# whenever i am giving constraints to content view which is embeded in scroll view then it is taking space on the top of view controller?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

In this i had placed a scroll view and content view on navigation controller but after giving constraints the content view is taking 64 top space can any one help me how to resolve ?[image]

And the constraints for the content view is mentioned here below[image]

and here scrolling was working but taking top space was the problem here as mentioned in above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard Viewcontroller properties UnCheck Automatically adjust scrolliview inset and try again

[image]

Comment: Got it bro thanks from yesterday onwards i was trying i was unable to get it

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Swift 3

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Objective-c :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```